# Smart way to multiply 3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, blas, dense-matrix

I have a quantum mechanics simulation where I need to multiply three matrices that look like this:

$$\rho(t_1)=U^\dagger \rho(t_0) \, U$$

where $U^\dagger$ is the hermitian conjugate of $U$. This evolves the density matrix $\rho$ from one time point to another time point. $U$ is called the evolution operator.

My question is: Is there a smart way to reduce the time required to do this matrix multiplication in C++? Is there anything better than using BLAS's `zgemm` 2 times (or `zhemm` 2 times, since the matrices are Hermitian)?

---

Additional information:

What I mean with smart is not only using a different library, but also finding a way to mathematically or computationally reduce the number of multiplications that have to be done in that operation.

The sizes of the matrices I deal with range from $2^7$ to $2^{15}$ in side-length (All these matrices are square matrices).

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer you, but it's often possible to avoid storing unitary matrices directly. Unitary matrices (e.g., http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node128.html) are more often stored internally as products of elementary unitary matrices, which can help.

Comment: Another comment that doesn't directly answer you, but sometimes only the action of matrices are needed on some known vectors, rather than the matrices themselves. If you can't get away with DGEMVs, you might be stuck with DGEMMs, or you could consider implementing a BLAS-like operation that does this sort of thing in one step and see if you can get any speedup.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you construct U from the underlying Hamiltonian? (diagonalize H...?)

Comment: @roygvib Matrix exponential of the Hamiltonian (with some factor).

Comment: I initially thought of split-operator things, but it may be not effective for general discrete models... Another thought is that if rho(t=0) can be represented somehow as \sum_k |k><k| with a relatively few states {|k>}, then the calculation may be reduced to matrix-vector things...

Comment: @roygvib The initial state is a linear super-position of all states (coherences are not zero) that's generated using a pi/2 pulse applied on the thermally polarized states. It's not a diagonal density matrix, unfortunately.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Matrix exponentiation is substantially more expensive than matrix multiplication, so perhaps that's where savings are more likely to be found (esp. for sizes as large as $2^{15}$) by tweaking the methods? Unless you've already checked that, of course.

Comment: @Kirill Actually exponentiating a Hermitian or anti-Hermitian matrix is not that complicated... All you need to do is calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of your matrix, and then exponentiate the eigenvalues, and multiply them. That probably is comparable to a matrix multiplication, but is not reducible, because it involves a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Have you considered working with the Cholesky (or low-rank) factor of $\rho(t_0)$ rather than with the matrix itself? This might reduce the number of products that you need to make, and it will preserve positive semidefiniteness across your computations.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni While you may have a point, remember that Cholesky decomposition is an $n^3$ operation, too. Do you have a suggestion on how the evolution process can be made cheap with Cholesky decomposition with net gain?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist It is already cheaper to use Cholesky factors for this computation alone, if I am not making mistakes with the costs: computing $\rho(t_0)=R^\dagger R$ costs $1/3n^3$ (counting with the traditional model addition=multiplication=1); computing $RU$ costs $n^3$ (because $R$ is triangular), and computing $(RU)^\dagger (RU)$ costs $n^3$ (because you only need to compute half of the entries). OTOH, computing $U^\dagger \rho(t_0)$ costs $2n^3$, and computing half of the entries of $(U^\dagger \rho(t_0))U$ costs $n^3$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Could you make your calculations an answer with full description of the symbols you're using and I'll study them for some time? Thank you!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I have flagged my comment for moderation attention to be converted to an answer (I can't do it myself in the SE interface, I'd have to retype all the formulas). As for the symbols, $R$ is an upper triangular Cholesky factor, $n$ is the size of all matrices involved, and all the rest appears already in your question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You could copy the text, and then right-click on the formulas, and get their LaTeX :) . Thanks for the clarification, anyway.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I can't migrate your comment through the mod interface. Your best option for converting your comment to a post is to cut and paste. If I did this myself, I would be the author, and you would not get credit for your answer.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry Thanks for your help anyway. I will probably file a bug on meta.se that this should be allowed somehow. It's even impossible to copy and paste the raw HTML code (which contains the un-mathjaxed equations), because additional comments are pulled in via AJAX and don't appear in the page source.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry Oh, and I found a workaround, of course only after doing everything by hand: one can right-click on an equation and select "math renderer->plain source" to disable all mathjax rendering; then the equations are displayed as their copy-and-pastable source.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered working with the Cholesky (or low-rank) factor of $\rho(t_0)$ rather than with the matrix itself? This might reduce the number of products that you need to make, and it has the additional benefit of preserving positive semidefiniteness across your computations.

It is already cheaper to use Cholesky factors for this computation alone, if I am not making mistakes with the costs: let $n$ be the side of each matrix appearing here; computing the upper triangular Cholesky factor $R$ such that $\rho(t_0)=R^\dagger R$ costs $\frac13 n^3$ (counting with the traditional model addition=multiplication=1); computing $RU$ costs $n^3$ (because $R$ is triangular), and computing $(RU)^\dagger (RU)$ costs $n^3$ (because you only need to compute half of the entries). OTOH, computing $U^\dagger \rho(t_0)$ costs $2n^3$, and then computing half of the entries of $(U^\dagger \rho(t_0))U$ costs $n^3$.

If $\rho(t_0)$ has low rank (which in the examples I saw when I studied quantum mechanics happened quite often for initial states), then one can start from a rectangular $R$ coming from the QR of its low-rank factor rather than a Cholesky decomposition, and this method is even cheaper. If you have to make more computations with your matrices after this triple product, then there may be additional savings: for instance, to compute products and solve linear system you can work with the low-rank factors directly rather than forming the last product.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if MATLAB (another language known for fast matrix operations) somehow does this in its own matrix multiplication scheme, or do I have to implement this myself?

Comment: @kyle No, as far as I know Matlab does not do this. The only similar-looking optimization that it does is computing $A^*A$ by computing only its lower or upper triangular -- but slightly more complex tasks are not similarly optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Considering only a computational point of view you could think of using  [cuBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#axzz4Nj04jj18)
the CUDA version of BLAS.

At the [link](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/05/31/matrix-multiplication-cuda-cublas-curand-thrust/) is an example of use.
In the last part there is a example in C++, with [thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#axzz4Nj04jj18).

Comment: I'm sorry. This is not a valid solution for me. I'm looking for a solution without CUDA or PHI.

Comment: Ok. I ask here, the following thing, because I can not comment on your question. Does your BLAS come from [Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software) ?

Comment: My BLAS is OpenBLAS.

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist Is the use of a more highly optimized vendor library like MKL instead of OpenBLAS a feasible alternative? Does OpenBLAS offer an alternative implementation of ZGEMM based on Winograd-Strassen? What are the typical dimensions of your matrices?

Comment: @njuffa Well, using MKL or BLAS isn't big a difference. That all makes a difference in the end calculation time but everything remains the same. A factor of 2? That's great, it still doesn't add information, as I can link my API to MKL and done. I'm hoping there are some smart decompositions or special calls that can make this computation much faster (especially that the same matrix exists there twice). Actually I wouldn't use the Winograd-Strassen algorithm in the interest of numerical stability. The size of my matrices are from $2^7$ up to $2^{15}$ (side-length).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You might want to clarify the original question to reflect the definition of "smart" used here, and include the matrix size information.

Comment: @njuffa Will do.

Comment: Are you ordering the two matrix multiplies in the more efficient way? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication

Comment: @BillGreene Thanks for that! I'll read it and provide feedback. Didn't realize the order made a difference.

Comment: @BillGreene aha... just realized it makes a difference only if the sizes are different. Sorry, but all these matrices are square matrices with the same sizes.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist  Maybe I missed the information, but: Has matrix U or $\rho$
 some particular properties?

Comment: @MauroVanzetto they are all Hermitian and U is unitary.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist In openBLAS site there is a [page](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/OpenBLAS-Extensions) with extension. In particular there is a function _gemm3m_, from [Intel description](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520861):

`The ?gemm3m routines perform a matrix-matrix operation with general complex matrices. These routines are similar to the ?gemm routines, but they use fewer matrix multiplication operations`

In the section _Note application_ they write `resulting in significant savings in compute time for large matrices.`
Have you seen this function?

Comment: @MauroVanzetto While this looks tempting, it doesn't exist for Hermitian matrices!!!! hemm() is cheaper because the number of operations is reduced by a factor of two!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist From your question I understand that you're interested in the cases: hermitian, general. Because you quote both functions zgemm and zhemm. Only for this reason I suggested gemm3m, i.e. in good faith :-)

Comment: Didn't know that gemm3m existed. Thanks for that piece!

Comment: Note that the stability of `gemm3m` may be an issue, too.